# Java String split method

Tags: java, string, split

I was working on a project and I needed to split Strings, but I had some trouble with it:
So, as an example:

```
String text = "cat(12;11,42;654)"
String[] split = text.split(something here);
```

So, I am in doubt about what to leave in "something here" if I want to split and get ONLY the numbers

```
split[0] = 12;
split[1] = 11;
split[2] = 42;
split[3] = 654;
```

I was looking for it in the java documentation, and came up with something like this:

```
String[] split = text.split("cat(|;|,|)");
```

But I'm not really sure if I would get the numbers like I wanted...

Comment: Why are you not sure? Did you run the code?

Comment: String.split(String) takes a regular expression as an argument and will split the string into tokens wherever the regex pattern matches. See the Oracle docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String). You need to use a regular expression such as `[;,]*`.

Comment: I was getting Index exception because it was not working as I wanted, thats why I posted it

Answer (score 2):

With `String#split()`, the best I think you can do (without changing the input String) is to split on non digit characters and ignore the first element of the resulting array

```
String text = "cat(12;11,42;654)";
String[] split = text.split("\\D+");
for (String element : split) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

prints

```
<emtpy string>
12
11
42
654
```

Otherwise, use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to find all matches of digits

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

prints

```
12
11
42
654
```